# qmake is not a file

Tags: python, macos, qt

I am trying to install pyqt on OS X but getting

```
configure.py: error: '/Users/vithahavya/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake' is not a file
```

I am following the instructions on a site which tells me to:

```
cd /var/tmp
cp /Users/gvincent/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz .
cp /Users/gvincent/Downloads/sip-4.15.5.tar.gz .
tar xvf PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvf sip-4.15.5.tar.gz
cd sip-4.15.5/
python3 configure.py -d ~/.env/ariane_mail/lib/python3.4/site-packages --arch x86_64
make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
cd ../PyQt-gpl-5.2.1/
python3 configure.py --destdir ~/.venv/mlp/lib/python3.8/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake
make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
~/.env/ariane_mail/bin/python -c "import PyQt5"**
```

The part that's giving me the error is the

```
python3 configure.py --destdir ~/.venv/mlp/lib/python3.8/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake
```

Comment: I really don't think you should be following instructions that involve Python 3.4 – it has been unsupported for 3 years.

Comment: Did you check whether or not that file actually exists?